# How to apply multiplier on margin constraint through xcodee?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

## Constraints

[image]

## Layout hierarchy

[image]

## Orange card top margin

[image]

## Description

I want a half portion of orange box (inside scroll view) to be always on top of `green color` image. So I applied multiplier property on `top constraint` of `orange box`

Considering `iPhone 4`

460/123 = Scroll view Height (460) / (167 - 44) (Orange box height - top margin of box in iphone 4)

I want to give multiplier on top margin of the orange box to it's superview i.e. `scrollView` to adjust dynamically in different screens with the same ratio.

What I have achieved is:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here and How can I approach the layout through xcode?

It's not dynamic. How can I achieve this layout? or How to add multiplier on vertical constraint through xcode?

Comment: Your green view does not respect safe area, you should decide if that should also happen for orange view

Answer (score 0):

`NSLayoutConstraint`'s `multiplier` is a *get-only* property. So you'll have to create a new instance each time you want to a different multiplier and deactivate the old constraint then activate the new constraint if you want to adjust the multiplier.

*What I recommend* doing instead *is adjust the `constant` of the constraint* instead, this way you will not need to create new constraint instances.

```
@IBOutlet weak var topMarginConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    if iphone4 {
        topMarginConstraint.constant = scrollView.frame.height / (orangeBoxView.height - iphone4TopMargin)
    } else if iphonex {
        topMarginConstraint.constant = scrollView.frame.height / (orangeBoxView.height - iphonexTopMargin)
    } else {
        // Implementations for other phones / screens...
    }
    view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other way except giving all devices height? Auto layout can't handle the size of the constraint on the basis of percentage?